# Custom status label not showing on admin grid Magento2

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, status

I am showing my custom modules grid in magento2 admin and that is showing fine with some filter options. In the start, I have only two status of the row - "New & Canceled" that was showing right in the grid column. 
Today I added some more statuses like - "Completed, Rescheduled".
Via forms respective row data updating successfully, but in grid view its showing wrong, always showing "New".

Here is my code in

> app/code/NameSpace/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/booking_booking_listing.xml

```
<column name="status" >
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Namespace\MyModule\Model\Booking\Source\IsActive</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">8</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

> Namespace\MyModule\Model\Booking\Source\IsActive.php

```
namespace Namespace\MyModule\Model\Booking\Source;

use Namespace\MyModule\Model\Booking;
use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

    class IsActive implements OptionSourceInterface
    {
        protected $booking;

        public function __construct(Booking $booking)
        {
            $this->booking = $booking;
        }

        public function toOptionArray()
        {
            $options[] = ['label' => '', 'value' => ''];
            $availableOptions = $this->booking->getAvailableStatuses();
            foreach ($availableOptions as $key => $value) {
                $options[] = [
                    'label' => $value->getText(),
                    'value' => $key,
                ];
            }
            return $options;
        }
    }
```

Returning array is  -

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array([label] => [value] => )
    [1] => Array([label] => New [value] => 1)
    [2] => Array([label] => Rescheduled [value] => 2)
    [3] => Array([label] => Completed [value] => 3)
    [4] => Array([label] => Canceled [value] => 0)
    [5] => Array([label] => Did not show up [value] => 4)
)
```

In admin grid filter its showing right options and filtering also right as per datbase values.

But In grid its not showing right label.

Here is the Grid screenshot -

[image]

Please check and let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
namespace Namespace\MyModule\Model\Booking\Source;

use Namespace\MyModule\Model\Booking;
use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

class IsActive implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    protected $booking;

    public function __construct(Booking $booking)
    {
        $this->booking = $booking;
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $availableOptions = $this->booking->getAvailableStatuses();
        foreach ($availableOptions as $key => $value) {
            $options[] = array('label' => $value->getText(),'value' => $key);
        }
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but solution not working ..